# To retrieve the value from session and assign it to a variable

Tags: asp.net

In the below code i  get all the ids in a arraylist and store it in a session in sample.aspx and retrieve the session value in test.aspx.Now i want to assign the project id to DataSet dsField in page load .How can i get that value separately.
sample.aspx

```
Button btnView = (Button)e.CommandSource;
Label lblProjectId = (Label)btnView.Parent.FindControl("ProjectID");
Label lblBatchID = (Label)btnView.Parent.FindControl("BatchID");
Label lblImageID = (Label)btnView.Parent.FindControl("ImageID");
Label lblReasons = (Label)btnView.Parent.FindControl("Reasons");
Label lblLayerID = (Label)btnView.Parent.FindControl("LayerID");
Label lblStatusID = (Label)btnView.Parent.FindControl("StatusID");
Label lblProcessID = (Label)btnView.Parent.FindControl("ProcessID");
ArrayList SearchUrlValues = new ArrayList();
SearchUrlValues.Add(lblProjectId);
SearchUrlValues.Add(lblBatchID);
SearchUrlValues.Add(lblProjectId);
SearchUrlValues.Add(lblImageID);
SearchUrlValues.Add(lblReasons);
SearchUrlValues.Add(lblLayerID);
SearchUrlValues.Add(lblStatusID);
SearchUrlValues.Add(lblProcessID);
Session["ProjectDetails"] = SearchUrlValues.ToArray();
Response.Write(SearchUrlValues);
```

test.aspx:

```
 Array SearchUrlValues = (Array)Session["ProjectDetails"];

 if (!IsPostBack)
 {
      DataSet dsField = GetFieldData(10);//how to assign projectid instead of 10
      gmasFieldsContr.dtFieldsInfo = dsField.Tables[0];
      gmasFieldsContr.EnumTable = dsField.Tables[1];
      gmasFieldsContr.RegularExpressionTable = dsField.Tables[3];
      gmasFieldsContr.BindData();
 }
public DataSet GetFieldData(int iProjectID)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlParameter[] SqlParam = new SqlParameter[1];

            SqlParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@i_ProjectID", SqlDbType.Int);
            SqlParam[0].Value = iProjectID;


            return ExecuteQuery(SqlParam, "spGetFieldData");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**

In Sample.aspx don't store SearchUrlValues as Array

```
Button btnView = (Button)e.CommandSource;
Label lblProjectId = (Label)btnView.Parent.FindControl("ProjectID");
Label lblBatchID = (Label)btnView.Parent.FindControl("BatchID");
Label lblImageID = (Label)btnView.Parent.FindControl("ImageID");
Label lblReasons = (Label)btnView.Parent.FindControl("Reasons");
Label lblLayerID = (Label)btnView.Parent.FindControl("LayerID");
Label lblStatusID = (Label)btnView.Parent.FindControl("StatusID");
Label lblProcessID = (Label)btnView.Parent.FindControl("ProcessID");
ArrayList SearchUrlValues = new ArrayList();
SearchUrlValues.Add(lblProjectId);
SearchUrlValues.Add(lblBatchID);
SearchUrlValues.Add(lblProjectId);
SearchUrlValues.Add(lblImageID);
SearchUrlValues.Add(lblReasons);
SearchUrlValues.Add(lblLayerID);
SearchUrlValues.Add(lblStatusID);
SearchUrlValues.Add(lblProcessID);
Session["ProjectDetails"] = SearchUrlValues; // Store it as ArrayList
Response.Write(SearchUrlValues);
```

Then test.aspx, convert Session object to ArrayList;

```
var SearchUrlValues = (ArrayList)Session["ProjectDetails"];

if (!IsPostBack)
{
    var projectId = int.Parse(SearchUrlValues[0].ToString());
    DataSet dsField = GetFieldData(projectId);//how to assign projectid instead of 10
    gmasFieldsContr.dtFieldsInfo = dsField.Tables[0];
    gmasFieldsContr.EnumTable = dsField.Tables[1];
    gmasFieldsContr.RegularExpressionTable = dsField.Tables[3];
    gmasFieldsContr.BindData();
}
```

By the way, please note that you're adding lblProjectId twice;

```
SearchUrlValues.Add(lblProjectId); // First
SearchUrlValues.Add(lblBatchID);
SearchUrlValues.Add(lblProjectId); // Second
```

Additionally, I would prefer to use an object to store these values in the session.

```
public class SearchUrlValues
{
    public int lblProjectId { get; set; }
    public int lblBatchID { get; set; }
    public int lblImageID { get; set; }
    public int lblReasons { get; set; }
    public int lblLayerID { get; set; }
    public int lblStatusID { get; set; }
    public int lblProcessID { get; set; }
}
```

Then, instead of arraylist;

```
var newSearchUrlValues = new SearchUrlValues()
{
    lblProjectId = lblProjectId,
    lblBatchID = lblBatchID,
    lblImageID = lblImageID,
    lblReasons = lblReasons,
    lblLayerID = lblLayerID,
    lblStatusID = lblStatusID,
    lblProcessID = lblProcessID
};

Session["ProjectDetails"] = newSearchUrlValues;
```

And retrieve it like;

```
var searchUrlValues = (SearchUrlValues)Session["ProjectDetails"];
var projectId = searchUrlValues.lblProjectId;
```

Comment: It throws an error Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type system.array in var projectId = (int)SearchUrlValues[0];

Comment: @user3319384 Okay, I've updated the answer. Session object needs to be converted to ArrayList.

Comment: it throws error on var SearchUrlValues = (ArrayList)Session["ProjectDetails"]; that Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'System.Collections.ArrayList'.

Comment: @user3319384 Okay, seen the problem, edited one more time. Basically you will store the object as ArrayList and retrieve it as ArrayList.

Comment: in this line                  var projectId = (int)SearchUrlValues[0]; it throws Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: @user3319384 Okay, one more time, that line was updated.

Comment: @user3319384 Okay, it's good to hear. Could you accept the answer..?

Comment: I Accept ur Answer. Sorry for late Acceptance

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This

```
 ArrayList SearchUrlValues = (ArrayList)Session["ProjectDetails"];

 if (!IsPostBack)
 {
      DataSet dsField = GetFieldData(Convert.ToInt32(SearchUrlValues[0].ToString()));
    //fetech 1st element of array List
      gmasFieldsContr.dtFieldsInfo = dsField.Tables[0];
      gmasFieldsContr.EnumTable = dsField.Tables[1];
      gmasFieldsContr.RegularExpressionTable = dsField.Tables[3];
      gmasFieldsContr.BindData();
 }
public DataSet GetFieldData(int iProjectID)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlParameter[] SqlParam = new SqlParameter[1];

            SqlParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@i_ProjectID", SqlDbType.Int);
            SqlParam[0].Value = iProjectID;


            return ExecuteQuery(SqlParam, "spGetFieldData");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: It throws an error Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression  of type system.array in   DataSet dsField = GetFieldData(SearchUrlValues[0].ToString());

Comment: it throws error onvar SearchUrlValues = (ArrayList)Session["ProjectDetails"]; that Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'System.Collections.ArrayList'